# Searching objects using Partial or complete Words contained into C# dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

**Good Morning**
I need to know something about searching in a C# Dictionary Using LinQ and Unity3d.

This is the thing:

I have the following classes :

```
public class SearcherTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI SearchTermText;
    public TMP_InputField  InputKeyWord;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ResultNumber;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ImpName;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ImpClass;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ImpHealth;
    public CompareInfo Comparer;
    public Dictionary<string, Data> ClassDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Data>();
    public Dictionary<string, Data> Result = new Dictionary<string, Data>();
    public List<string> LstResultKeys = new List<string>();
    public int NavCounter;
    void Start()
    {
        Comparer = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
        NavCounter = -1;
        ClassDictionary.Add("Byzard", new Data(5, "Paladin"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Ingrid", new Data(5, "Paladin"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Carolina",new Data(8, "Warrior"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Aragorn", new Data(8, "Warrior"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Boromir", new Data(8, "Warrior"));

        ClassDictionary.Add("Laila", new Data(15, "Tank"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Xenua", new Data(15, "Tank"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Leticia", new Data(15, "Tank"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Lila", new Data(15, "Tank"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Yamasaki", new Data(15, "Tank"));

        ClassDictionary.Add("Jairo", new Data(3, "Necromancer"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Felix", new Data(6, "Crafter"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Farid", new Data(4, "Crafter"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Willhem", new Data(4, "Crafter"));

        ClassDictionary.Add("Ivhan", new Data(9,"Support"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Karen", new Data(9,"Support"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Will",  new Data(9,"Support"));

        ClassDictionary.Add("JN", new Data(5, "Wizard"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Lion", new Data(5, "Archer"));
        ClassDictionary.Add("Uyial", new Data(5, "Archer"));
    }

    public void Query( )
    {
        string _SearchKeyWord;
        _SearchKeyWord = InputKeyWord.text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTermText.text))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            LstResultKeys.Clear();
            Result = SearchQuery(ClassDictionary, _SearchKeyWord);
            LstResultKeys = Result.Keys.ToList();
            foreach (var item in Result)
            {
                Debug.Log(item.Key);
            }
        }

    }
    private Dictionary<string , Data> SearchQuery ( Dictionary<string , Data> _Dictionary, string _KeyWord)
    {
        return _Dictionary
            .Where(p => p.Value.Class == _KeyWord)
            .GroupBy(k => k.Key)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.First().Value);
    }
    public void SelectNextFindedItem()//It Allows me navigate between results (Next result)
    {
        NavCounter += 1;
        if (NavCounter >=LstResultKeys.Count)
        {
            NavCounter = 0;
        }
        if (Result.TryGetValue(LstResultKeys[NavCounter],out Data _data))
        {
            ImpName.text = LstResultKeys[NavCounter];
            ImpClass.text = _data.Class;
            ImpHealth.text = _data.HealthAmount.ToString();
        }
        int mNavCounterUI = NavCounter + 1;
        int mLstResultKeys = LstResultKeys.Count;
        ResultNumber.text = string.Format("{0}/{1}", mNavCounterUI, mLstResultKeys);
    }
    public void SelectPrevFindedItem()//It Allows me navigate between results (previously result)
    {
        NavCounter -= 1;
        if (NavCounter <0)
        {
            NavCounter = LstResultKeys.Count - 1;
        }
        if (Result.TryGetValue(LstResultKeys[NavCounter], out Data _data))
        {
            ImpName.text = LstResultKeys[NavCounter];
            ImpClass.text = _data.Class;
            ImpHealth.text = _data.HealthAmount.ToString();
        }
        int mNavCounterUI = NavCounter+1;
        int mLstResultKeys = LstResultKeys.Count;
        ResultNumber.text = string.Format("{0}/{1}", mNavCounterUI, mLstResultKeys);
    }
    public void PrintData(string _name, string _Class, string _healt)
    {
        ImpName.text = _name;
        ImpClass.text = _Class;
        ImpHealth.text = _healt;
    }
}
//Holds Basic data about characters
public class Data
{
    public int HealthAmount;
    public string Class;
    public Data (int _HealthAmount, string _class)
    {
        HealthAmount = _HealthAmount;
        Class = _class;
    }
}
```

I also have a **searching** bar for this purposes:
If i type "Warrior" , I should get all "Warrior" characters , sorted by name.
But if Type "War" there is nothing in OutPut Dictionary.

In SQL syntax, I can use **"Like % War %"** and it should show me:

- "Carolina", "8";
- "Aragorn", "8";
- "Boromir", "8";
  But in C# using LinQ I do not know how can i do that ... The main question is 
  **How can i do that in C# using dictionarys and LinQ** ? 
  **Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [string.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.contains).

Personally I would then include both, either the key containing the keyword or the value type.

I guessed you would also want to have multiple values, not only the first one.

```
private Dictionary<string, Data> SearchQuery(Dictionary<string, Data> _Dictionary, string _KeyWord)
{
    return _Dictionary
        // Use string.Contains on both keys and values
        .Where(p => p.Value.Class.Contains(_KeyWord) || p.Key.Contains(_KeyWord))
        // GroupBy for a dictionary is redundant afaik since every key is unique
        // First order by keys then by the values
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key).ThenBy(x => x.Value.Class)
        // return all Values not only linking all keys to only the first value ...
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = ClassDictionary.Keys.Where(k => k.Contains("War"));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it answers the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.